# Top most view controller with multiple window scenes in iOS13

Tags: uiwindow, uiapplication, ios13, uiscene

I'm conforming my application to use multiple windows on *iPadOS* with *iOS 13*, as far as I know I cannot access to `UIApplication` window directly due to it's deprecation, how can I get the top most view controller?

Until *iOS12* I use this working solutions, can you suggest an alternative?

```
+(UIViewController *)topMostViewController
{
    UIViewController *vc = [[UIApplication sharedApplication].delegate.window rootViewController];
    while(vc.presentedViewController)
    {
        vc = vc.presentedViewController;
    }
    return vc;
}
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How get current keywindow equivalent for multi window SceneDelegate Xcode 11?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57009283/how-get-current-keywindow-equivalent-for-multi-window-scenedelegate-xcode-11)

Comment: not fully, as i keep learning it's always better to user `view.window`

Answer (score -2):

see: [How get current keywindow equivalent for multi window SceneDelegate Xcode 11?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57009283/how-get-current-keywindow-equivalent-for-multi-window-scenedelegate-xcode-11)

deprecated:
<s>Have you tried `Application.shared.keyWindow?.rootViewController`? The *keyWindow* (or `mainWindow` if you like) is the important part here.</s>

Comment: `keyWindow` is deprecated in iOS 13